# Pandas - Groupby percentage of subtotal

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a df that I would like to group by two columns. What I would like to display is the percentage of the sum of each item in level=0 (i.e. sum of 'a' and sum of 'b' in the below example) for each item in level=1 (i.e. 'c','d','e' in the example).

Example:

I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b'], 'col2': ['c','c','d','d','e','c','c','d','d','e'],'col3':[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]})

col1 col2  col3
0    a    c     2
1    a    c     2
2    a    d     2
3    a    d     2
4    a    e     2
5    b    c     2
6    b    c     2
7    b    d     2
8    b    d     2
9    b    e     2
```

And I would like to obtain this:

```
col1  col2
a     c       0.4
      d       0.4
      e       0.2
b     c       0.4
      d       0.4
      e       0.2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First aggregate `sum` by both columns and then divide by [`DataFrame.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) `sum` per first level of `MultiIndex`:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['col1','col2']).sum()
df1 = df1.div(df1.sum(level=0), level=0)
print (df1)
           col3
col1 col2      
a    c      0.4
     d      0.4
     e      0.2
b    c      0.4
     d      0.4
     e      0.2
```